# SymmetricDS unidirectional replication

Tags: centos7, oracle12c, symmetricds

I'm implementing SymmetricDS (vs 3.9.4), one way replication (server => client), and I have some questions:

server and client are Oracle 12c in 2 different CentOS 7 machines.

1. On client I need only to install and start symmetric service,
   right?
2. I need to create the SYM tables on client? Since this
   replication is only from server to client I think it is not
   necessary. right?
3. how client communicate with server? just based on
   the sync.url property on engine file?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. on client you'll need to install the symmetricDs service
2. you can create the `sym_*` tables or leave symmetricDs to create them. `sym_*` tables are necessary for symmetricDs to function
3. yes, the client will use the `sync.url` to connect to the server, register and request the initial load. Then the server will either push new syncing data to the client or the client will pull the new data from server. It depends how this communication is configured